# Issue displaying title on tab when opening PDFs on iOS

Tags: html, ios, ipad, pdf, mobile-safari

Does anybody know if there's a way to force iOS mobile safari to display the filename of a pdf rather than the URL in the tab?  We have some PDFs on our site that don't have the "Title" meta data stored in them, so when you open them in mobile safari the tab just displays a number, which is the end of the URL.

Or if not, is there a way to dictate what the browser should display as the tab title?

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this, sorry.